# sql command , executeNonQuery()

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I have a web form which takes data from a user. User enters the values and clicks add button. I want to insert the values entered by user into the database. But when I run the project. it gives the following error at `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`

> SqlException was unhandled by user code:
>   incorrect syntax near the keyword 'of'.

What is the problem and how to fix that issue?

The query is:

```
insert into EMPLOYEES
    (EMP_ID,
    FIRST_NAME,
    SECOND_NAME,
    THIRD_NAME,
    LAST_NAME,
    GENDER,
    DATE_OF_BIRTH,
    PLACE_OF_BIRTH,
    NATIONALITY,
    PHONE_NUMBER,
    DEPT_ID,
    JOB_ID,
    START_DATE)
values
    ('" + txtid.Text + "',
    '" + txtFirst.Text + "',
    '" + txtsecond.Text + "',
    '" + txtthird.Text + "',
    '" + txtlast.Text + "',
    '" + s + "',
    '" + txtdob.Text + "',
    '" + txtPlace.Text + "',
    '" + txtnat.Text + "',
    '" + txtphone.Text + "',
    '" + txtdep.Text + "',
    '" + txtpos.Text + "',
    '" + txtstart.Text + "')
```

Comment: Please edit the query into the question

Comment: I'd also recommend using parameterized queries. Apart of being more secure it is also easier since you don't have to pay attention to whether you have to escape strings or not.

Comment: You will probably not find errors in the SQL.  Building a SQL command in this fashion (string concatenation) is dangerous, both from a coding point of view and a security point.  Use a parametrized query.

Answer (score 4):

You should not concatenate together your SQL statements - use parametrized queries instead to avoid SQL injection but also syntax errors.

Here is how you should adjust your code:

```
string sql = @"INSERT INTO employees (emp_id,first_name, second_name , third_name , last_name , gender , date_of_birth , place_of_birth ,nationality , phone_number, dept_id , job_id , start_date)
              VALUES(@emp_id,@first_name, @second_name , @third_name , @last_name , @gender , @date_of_birth , @place_of_birth ,@nationality , @phone_number, @dept_id , @job_id , @start_date)";
SqlCommand exeSQL = new SqlCommand(sql, cn);
cn.Open();
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emp_id", txtid.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@first_name", txtFirst.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@second_name", txtsecond.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@third_name", txtthird.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@last_name", txtlast.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", s);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date_of_birth", txtdob.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@place_of_birth", txtPlace.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nationality", txtnat.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone_number", txtphone.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dept_id", txtdep.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@job_id", txtpos.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@start_date", txtstart.Text);
exeSQL.ExecuteNonQuery();
```