# How to update date in SQL Server through C# using a stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio

I'm having trouble updating the DOB of a client in my project. I use stored procedures to do this and every time I try updating it gives me even though I specified it my stored procedure

> Column 'dateBirth' does not belong to table dataSet.

Stored procedure:

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspUpdateDate]
     @clientID INT,
     @dateBirth DATE
 AS
 BEGIN
     UPDATE Client
     SET DOB = @dateBirth
     WHERE ClientID = @clientID
 END
```

Update function:

```
 public void Update(string proc, string[] param, string[] value)
 {
        updateCommand = new SqlCommand(proc, connectionString.UConnect);
        updateCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        for (int x = 0; x < param.Length; x++)
            updateCommand.Parameters.Add('@' + param[x], SqlDbType.VarChar, 0, param[x]).Value = value[x];

        for (int x = 0; x < param.Length; x++)
        {
            if (value[x] == "")
                dataTable.Rows[0][param[x]] = DBNull.Value;
            else
                dataTable.Rows[0][param[x]] = value[x];
        }

        dataAdapter.UpdateCommand = updateCommand;
        dataAdapter.Update(dataTable);
 }
```

Here's the code in Visual Studio that I use:

```
 private void btnSaveC_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
        string nodeTag = treeView.SelectedNode.Tag.ToString();
        Select("uspSelectClientByID",
           new string[] { "clientID" },
           new string[] { nodeTag });
        Update("uspUpdateDate", new string[] { "clientID", "dateBirth" },
            new string[] { nodeTag, DateTime.Now.ToString() });
 }
```

I know my function works because I tried using it with a different column with a `VARCHAR` data type.

Comment: where in your code are you `Executing` the update statement.. do a simple google search on how to Update a Table using C# and Sql server.. there are tons of examples for example `google search the following C# Command.ExecuteNonQuery()` and see the many yielded results..

Comment: here is a simple link from a previous stack overflow posting that you can follow there are tons more out there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28676319/sql-command-executenonquery

Comment: Just at a glance, I noticed that you are converting the date you want to send to string, however, your stored procedure is expecting that value to be a date. Perhaps you should look there.

Comment: Show the code for your `Update` function.

Comment: There you go, mate. I think (most likely) It's because of the whole string thing I did

Comment: If you execute your stored procedure from within the database manually, does it work? Saying a column doesn't exist is one thing. An invalid parameter is another. Invalid data formats (passing a string and using `SqlDbType.VarChar` when the procedure param is a `DATE`) is another thing.

Comment: Yeah it works when I manually do it in in MSSQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable in the stored procedure should be similar to the column name. For instance, if the column is `LastName` on your table then the variable in your stored procedure should be `lastName` or some similar variation; you'll run to an error in Visual Studio otherwise. In my case, putting `dob` as the variable worked. I'm passing strings to be converted to a `VARCHAR` because of the code in my function:

```
updateCommand.Parameters.Add('@' + param[x], SqlDbType.VarChar, 0, param[x]).Value = value[x]
```